# Google Calendar API Sharing Example

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I am looking for examples of share calendar and share event using google calendar API in any programming language java, .net, java script.

Thanks,
Aqeel

Comment: You'd probably want to make your question more specific before you keep getting voted down...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much this will help, but I have an example here using scala with the ical4j library to read a shared/public google calendar:

http://github.com/kevinwright/lsug-website/tree/master/src/main/scala/org/lsug/ical4scala/